# Dialogflow parameter entity similar to Alexa's AMAZON.SearchQuery

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've developed an Alexa skill and now I am in the process of porting it over to a Google action. At the center of my Alexa skill, I use [AMAZON.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery) slot type to capture free-form text messages. Is there an entity/parameter type that is similar for google actions? As an example, see the following interactions from my Alexa skill:

Alexa, tell my test app to say hello everyone my name is Corey

-> slot value = "hello everyone my name is Corey"

Alexa, tell my test app to say goodbye friends I'm logging off

-> slot value = "goodbye friends I'm logging off"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have a few options depending on exactly what you want to accomplish as part of your Action.

**Using @sys.any**

The most equivalent entity type in Dialogflow is the built-in type `@sys.any`. To use this, you can create an Intent, give it a sample phrase, and select any of the text that would represent what you want included in the parameter. Then select the `@sys.any` entity type.

Afterwards, it would look something like this.

[image]

You may be tempted to select *all* the text in the sample phrase. Don't do this, since it messes up the training and parsing. Instead use...

**Fallback Intents**

The Fallback Intent is something that isn't available for Alexa. It is an Intent that gets triggered if there are no other Intents that would match. (It has some additional abilities when you're using Contexts, but thats another topic.)

Fallback Intents will send the entire contents of what the user said to your fulfillment webhook. To create a Fallback Intent, you can either use the default one that is provided, or from the list of Intents select the three dot menu *next to* the create button and then select "Create Fallback Intent"

[image]

[image]

So you may be tempted to just create a Fallback Intent if all you want is all the text that the user says. If that is the case, there is an easier way...

**Use the Action SDK**

If you have your own Natural Language Processing / Understanding (NLP/NLU) system, you don't need Dialogflow in the mix. You just want the Assistant to send you the result of the speech-to-text processing.

You can do this with the [Action SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/). In many ways, it is similar to how ASK and Dialogflow work, but it has very basic Intents - most of the time it will just send your webhook a TEXT intent with the contents of what the user has said and let you process it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! My skill is quite simple and understanding what the user intends isn't that complicated. Using the Action SDK directly is enticing... I'm not a fan of messing about in the dialogflow UI anyways... Do you have any recommended tutorials for doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Most of the Platform based ASR systems are mainly built on 3 main parameters
1. Intent - all sorts of logic will be written here
2. Entity - On which the intent will work
3. Response - After executing all the process this is what the user will able to hear.

There is another important parameter called webhook, it is used to interact with an external API.

the basic functionalities are the same for all the platforms, already used dialogflow(google developed this platform- supports most of the platforms even Alexa too), Alexa, Watson(developed by IBM).

remember one thing that to get a precise result giving proper training phases is very much important as the o/p hugely depends on the sample input.